# django app_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug' error

Tags: python, django

hello I want to create a simple Django blog and I want to take mivies details from some simple movies list but I take this error :

```
app_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'
```

I have follow docs and I think my code is correct but anytime I take this error.

models.py

```
class app_movies(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug_title = models.SlugField()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^movies-details/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', views.movies_details, name='movies_details'),
```

views.py

```
def movies_list(request):
    return render(request, 'movies_list.html',{'movies':app_movies.objects.filter(createddate__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-createddate')})


def movies_details(request,slug_title):
    movies=app_movies.objects.all()
    app_movies=get_object_or_404(movies, slug=slug_title)
    return render(request, 'movies_details.html',{'movies':movies,'app_movies':app_movies})
```

html tag :

```
<a  href="/movies-details/{{movies.slug_title}}">View Project <span ></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your error is actually about `movies_details`, you have called the argument to that function `slug_title` but the URL pattern has just `slug`. Those need to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

In **views.py** pass `slug` as field and then it should be equal to model field `slug_title`.

```
def movies_details(request,slug):
    movies=app_movies.objects.all()
    app_movies=get_object_or_404(movies, slug_title=slug)
    return render(request, 'movies_details.html',{'movies':movies,'app_movies':app_movies})
```